# typesetting LaTeX codes in a question

Tags: discussion

I know this is a stupid question, but I am encountering some problems with my thesis. I would like to post a question about an error in a tabular format. How do I write down the codes so that someone can see them in the grey-box like this one? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you indent each line of code with four spaces, it will look like that. See also the [formatting guide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for details and more style tips.

Comment: The simplest is to  type your code, highlight it with the mouse/trackpad and click the pair of braces in the icon bar above the edit window.

Comment: See [How do I mark code blocks?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1193)